# How does #if macro work in C?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

MyMacros.h:

```
int const TESTING = 1;

#define INFO(MSG) fprintf(stderr, "INFO :: %s\n", MSG);
```

MyProgram.c:

```
#if TESTING
    INFO("File 'data.dat' opened correctly.");
#endif
```

The message isn't printed to the screen. However if I do this:

```
#if TESTING < 1
```

It works and prints the message. Hunh???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing preprocessing and compiling.

The line `int const TESTING = 1;` is not understood by C preprocessor, it doesn't know the value of `TESTING`. In fact, neither the C compiler can use that value at the compile time (unlike C++ with better support of `const` expressions).

It is common pattern in C to define constants using the `#define` directive (again, unlike C++):

```
#define TESTING 1
```

And note the absence of a semicolon at the end of this line. Semicolons are required by the compiler, not the preprocessor.

Comment: So I were to replace that with: `#define TESTING 1` would that work?

Comment: Sorry I am getting the following error: "error: token ";" is not valid in preprocessor expressions" on the `#define TESTING 1;`

Comment: Thanks! It worked!!! But why?? Aren't all macro statements supposed to end with a semicolon?